# Replace cells content based of different conditions

Tags: google-sheets

imagine I have a column with a list of brand, how can I search for different brand name and replace their name with anoter label automatically?
If it was only 1 condition, I could do
`IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B27), "nike"), "Sport Shop", B27)`

but what if I have 2 or more conditions-label to apply?
Here is an example:
[image]
Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: looks like you need a VLOOKUP. hard to tell just from your image

Comment: The problem is the regex...

Comment: Please read the linked duplicates and test the answers there for a few minutes

Comment: @TheMaster thanks, I've checked them but my case it's a little bit different. I want to map, for instance, "Amazon Supermarket", "Amazon Online", "Amazon whatevet", all of them in the "Supermarket" category. So I need a sort of regex for the Lookup...

Comment: `VLOOKUP` supports wildcards. See official documentation. If after research, you're unable to figure it out  or  think it's impossible without REGEX, Ask a new question with expected output and input as a text  table. For your future question,

Comment: make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: You are totally right! Thanks for the suggestion!